# CRM 2011 JavaScript - Modify Date From One Field And Set To Another

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to pull out a date from one field, modify that date and set that value into another, here is my code:

```
var startDate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_startdate').getValue();
var expiryDate = startDate.getDate()+3; //Add 3 days

var expiryField = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_expirydate').setValue(expiryDate);
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?  I've been at this for a while now and I fear I'm missing something blatently obvious..

Thanks in advance.

EDIT;

When the script fires, 1/1/1970 is set in the expiry field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work

```
var startDate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_startdate').getValue();
var expiryDate = new Date();
expiryDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+3); //Add 3 days

var expiryField = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_expirydate').setValue(expiryDate);
```

Comment: One problem with the above code: var expiryDate = new Date(); will set expiry date to the *current* date.
expiryDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+3); will take the day of month of startDate and add 3 days, then set the day of month for expiryDate to the resultant day of month. This ignores month and year. If startDate is not within the current month or year, expiryDate will be. 
It would be better to have:
var expiryDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate()+3);

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the function [`getDate()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp) returns the day of the month. So the result of

```
var startDate = new Date("January 11, 2013");
var expiryDate = startDate.getDate()+3;
```

would be the *number* 14.

I assume that this gets converted to a Date using the Date(milliseconds) overload which represents

> [Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)

Therefore you see the this value.

So, the solution which lazarus has posted shows the correct approach.